# How to tell if cell was inserted or reloaded in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to set different styles for cells that I have inserted compared to reloaded ones.

I am inserting my cells like the following:

```
[tempArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
[[self tableView] beginUpdates];
[[self tableView] insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)tempArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[[self tableView] endUpdates];
```

Is there a way for me to do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (cell was inserted) {
      cell.mylabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
      cell.mylabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use the cell's tag value for that. The default value is 0, change it to 1 or what else.

Comment: hmm but both would be using the same cell class, so dont think i can differentiate them by tag value since they will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case for maintaining the state of a table view cell, the right answer is to keep the state in your model.  In other words, if tempArray is your model containing a collection of objects that describe the table's contents, add a BOOL attribute to those objects meaning something like `userAdded`.

Then your "cell was inserted" pseudo-code can become:

```
MyModelClass *modelElement = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (modelElement.userAdded) {
    cell.mylabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else {
  cell.mylabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```